# Badge Notification within a Universal Windows App

Tags: win-universal-app

There seems to be a lot of documentation on showing badge notifications on Tiles in UWP apps. However, is there any way to show a badge notification on navigation buttons within the application itself. This seems to be a very common scenario for mobile apps. When I log into the facebook app, one of the tabs (notification) shows me a number of new notifications. Are there any sample how to implement this in universal windows app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: Your app updated the badge in the first place so your app already knows what number to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All notifications inside the application are custom controls.
For Universal Windows App badge is only cerated to show how many notificatiins you have to encourage user to open it.
If you would like to create custom badges in your UWP app you can for example put Image control with badge graphic with text block next to it to show number of new notifications. Both control can be placed in the StackPanel with Orientation set to Horizontal.
Let me know if you got it or need more help and explanation.

Comment: Thanks Danny for your reply. I was hoping that there is already a recommended way to do this as this is so common. I will give it a try myself to see if I can build the custom control.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need more help with that ;)

Comment: Just wanted to post an update that I was able to do this by using an ellipse instead of an image. I have a textblock on top of the ellipse that shows the number of alerts. The textblock is bound to a datacontext so this allows me to easily update the number of alerts. Here is the code that worked for me. Might help someone else too

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an update that I was able to do this by using an ellipse instead of an image. I have a textblock on top of the ellipse that shows the number of alerts. The textblock is bound to a datacontext so this allows me to easily update the number of alerts. Here is the code that worked for me. Might help someone else too

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="Alerts"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Margin="5" Width="40" Height="40" Fill="White" />
                        <TextBlock Name="TbAlerts" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding AlertsCount}"  >
                            <TextBlock.DataContext>
                                <UIModels:BadgeAlert/>
                            </TextBlock.DataContext>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi @user6248121 could you please put the complete example?